# TFS workitem readonly

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2015, tfs-2015

Suppose the case:

When a User create a workitem associated with another User, and that other User put workitem as active, I want the workitem be read-only to owner until it is resolved in status.

That is, the workitem owner can only make change the workitem when it has resolved or when it returns to his name.

Comment: I think this could be possible by making all fields read only based on the AssignedTo field - but it would be a lot of work to setup and maintain - I'd try and go for *Attitudinal fix* instead.

Answer (score 0):

**You cannot limit access to an entire work item based on a user’s role in TFS.**  You can only limit transitions, and access to individual fields, but for very large and complex work item types, this is cumbersome and fragile.

Moreover, you also cannot block an entire set of users from all work items in an area. You need to just restrict a single work item type from the related users or those in a specific role across all projects and areas.

So, even this can be achieved by the way just as *DaveShaw* commented above, it's also not recommend you to do this.

Comment: I'm using TFS's workitens to DBA's team apply scripts in homologation/production, so, i'm creating a workitem and linking BD's scripts in it. To make sure that nobody will change the script after i created the workitem, i'm lockin the scripts in TFS. 
I think there is another tool or method to make it safer and smarter

Comment: Please see my answer in this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40070246/workflow-to-apply-scripts-in-homologation-production/40086599#40086599