# Workflow to apply scripts in homologation/production

Tags: tfs, workflow, database-administration, devops

I'm using TFS's workitens to DBA's team apply scripts in homologation/production, so, i'm creating a workitem and linking BD's scripts in it. To make sure that nobody will change the script after i created the workitem, the DBAs team is locking the scripts in TFS before aplly. I think there is another tool or method to make it safer and smarter

Comment: So who can change the workitem in your scenario? The workitem owner?

Comment: only the person who is associated at that time.

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try with [this workaround](http://www.tfswhisperer.com/post/2013/01/14/Making-TFS-2012-Work-Item-Types-Read-Only-Based-on-User-Roles) by *Angela Dugan*, In short the solution of Angela works as follows:

1. Add a field [UserAccessDenied] to a work item but do not show this
   on the form In the desired state add a rule [REQUIRED] for a certain
   group
2. Because you can not enter a value, you can never save the work item,
   so it is “sort of” read only.

For example, after setting only you in can make a state transition from [Active] to [Resolved]

Comment: But then I could change the workitem, and that's a problem. Who creates the workitem can not change it until it is resolved or returned to him.